# Indesign real-time package for collaboration

Tags: package, adobe-indesign, collaboration

I manage a team of designers working on Indesign.
When we work on a project, it often happens that a designer has to work on the project of another. We work with Dropbox for Business.
But when we take the work of another designer, there is often missing links and fonts.

Is there a plugin or a way to develop a plugin that would allow, when we create a new indd file (or for the protection of the same file):

- Automatically create a "Links" folder and another "Document fonts" at side of the indd file
- Systematically add a new link or new typography in the corresponding folder?

To simplify: each action on font or on a link, make a kind of "Indesign Package" in real time?

If this is not a solution, do you have any solutions to meet this need?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a specific script or plugin that does this.

However, it should be possible to write a script with an eventhandler with a beforeClose event that runs certain script commands every time a user closes a document (or even every time a user adds, changes or deletes a link). At this point the script could run some copyLink commands on all the images and fonts (?) placing them all in the folders next to the document.

The whole script could be made a startup script, so it becomes active anytime any user runs InDesign.

(I'm actually not sure, if fonts can be copied so easily. Worst case scenario would be that the script would need to run some packaging command to gather the fonts somewhere, copy them over to where you need them and then delete the rest of the temporary package.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider Creative Cloud Libraries ? They are meant to allow sharing assets within a team. Apart form that, you users would need to have a same access to the file system (a common drive letter for the network path for example).
Another solution would be to use a DAM solution so users would link files from the DAM.
Eventually, you could sure think of a script as mdomino offered.